# Power BI - SQL to DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an rdat field that I have to convert to a date field which I know how to do in sql but am new to DAX and I'm not sure how to do this

```
CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, RDAT_ENTERED +5843, 0), 1)
```

in Power BI. I can fix on the sql side so that it just brings in the data but I would still like to know how this would look in BI.

Comment: What is a **rdat** field? post some samples, if you can convert that column value to a string it is very possible you can get a valid date in Power BI.

Comment: Sorry our rdat field contains values like this
34575
33123
33123
33123
33123
33123
33123
33123
34586
And I can Convert in sql to the correct date format but I was just curious how this would be done power bi

Answer (score 2):

It seems your data uses the **SQL SERVER** [**EPOCH**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Computing) to represent dates so `RDAT_ENTERED + 5843` means a determinated number of days from `1/1/1900`. You can use that information to convert it to human dates via DAX or Power Query.

Create a calculated column either in Dax or Power Query (informally known as "M")

**DAX in Power BI and Power Pivot**

```
HumanDate = DATE(1900,1,1) + [RDAT_ENTERED] + 5843
```

**M language in Power Query**

```
=Date.AddDays(DateTime.FromText("1900-01-01"), [RDAT_ENTERED] + 5843)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize the context of your question and recognize the [excellent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035847/2226988) answer by @alehandro. However, a few suggested best practices:

- SQL *is* a BI tool
- Transformations to standard data types should be at as low a level as possible
- Magic numbers should not be used `DECLARE @EPOCH_RDAT DATE = { d '1916-01-01' };`
- Function parameters should be used as intended: `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, RDAT_ENTERED, @EPOCH_RDAT);`